# Can I use InputStream returned from ResultSet.getBinaryStream() after closing the result set?

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, resultset

I want to read my Blob data in chunks using getBinaryStream() method, as I expect some blobs to be big, so I produced following method:

```
public InputStream getBlob(Long id) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select blob_contents from some_table where id = ?");
        stmt.setLong(1, id);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getBinaryStream("blob_contents");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it safe to close the resultSet `rs` and statement `stmt` in finally block and then return the stream from this method? Is it safe to process the stream after that?

What I know already:

- In my junits based on h2 database it works.
- My code works ok on oracle db.
- I've found somthing about blobs in [ResultSet's javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29), but I'm not sure if this applies to the `getBinaryStream` method:

> The closing of a ResultSet object does not close the Blob, Clob or NClob objects created by the ResultSet. Blob, Clob or NClob objects remain valid for at least the duration of the transaction in which they are creataed, unless their free method is invoked.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Interesting question, I don't think the specification says anything about this explicitly.

Comment: It seems to work fine, statement and result set is closed and I can read from the stream after it is returned from that method. However can I be sure, that this will be always the case? Or am I just lucky?

Comment: I am not sure if this will apply to all JDBC drivers. Also in auto commit, it might be that closing the result set triggers the commit, which then will close the blob anyway.

Comment: I don't use auto commit, so at least I am sure, that stream is processed within transaction. I use ojdbc6.jar for oracle 11g (11.2.0.3) .

Comment: Correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248443/999367   Implementation may be further simplified with the usage of Apache's AutoCloseInputStream.